# Google Sign-In for iOS using Xamarin throws exception logs point to podfile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Trying to implement the Google Sign-In for IOS in a Xamarin project.  Right on the Google page where it generates your GoogleService-Info.plist file, it says, "Insure you have CocoaPods installed and configured for your project. In you Podfile, include the following: pod 'Google/SignIn'".

And sure enough, the log on the Mac shows a similar error when going through the initial configuration.

But, I can't find anything that really tells me how to add a "Podfile" to a Xamarin IOS project (from within Visual Studio 2017, running on Windows 10).

So, when it comes time to actually click the Sign-In with Google button, in an IOS 10.3 IPhone 6 simulator, it throws an exception,

> "Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFString
>   countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x608000047200".

I can only hope it is really because of a missing component that the Podfile is supposed to resolve.

Saw a sample from a year ago that supposedly worked, but with what seems to be current right now, I can't get it to.

Update: 
   The sample I am trying to use, creates a custom class for the View so it can implement a custom Renderer, and a custom class for the page, again, so it can implement a custom Renderer.  The View Renderer simply does:

```
signInButton = new SignInButton();
signInButton.Style = ButtonStyle.Wide;
signInButton.ColorScheme = ButtonColorScheme.Dark;
SetNativeControl(signInButton);
```

The Google button shows up, but when you click, you get the exception listed above.

Comment: You cannot add podfiles to a Xamarin.iOS project, these are only for ios projects in Xcode with objective-c/swift. What's the code you are using to do the Google SignIn ?

Comment: The Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn NuGet package, v4.0.1.2.

Comment: Could you update your post and show the code where you configure the Google Sign in Button?

Comment: I bailed on the attempt for now, but before I did, I downloaded the code at [this GitHub location](https://github.com/renzska/GoogleSignInForms), which was supposedly a working project at the time (looks like it was over a year ago) and it also failed the same way. Which doesn't surprise me since that is what I was using as a guide (and also this [xamarin Google Sign-In for IOS](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleiossignin) site.

Comment: I'm back at this again with the same results of course.  I added info about how the button gets created.  I didn't add all the code, because it is available at https://github.com/renzska/GoogleSignInForms.

Answer (score 0):

A recent update to Xamarin required an update to XCode.  With the update to XCode 9,the problem went away, and Google authorization is working.